# Does Flyway support executing multiple SQL scripts called from one SQL script?

Tags: flyway

I am trying to execute multiple scripts from one SQL file, running it in sequence. E.g. if I have **V1.0__Test0.sql**, and the contents are:

```
@V1.1__Test1.sql;
@V1.1__Test2.sql;
```

If I run the migrate option, I get an **ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement error**. Does Flyway support what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: The `@` is a **SQL\*Plus** command not a standard SQL statement. So that can't be used through JDBC (or any other tool that is not SQL\*Plus)

Answer (score 1):

No. This is documented in the limitations: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle.html#limitations

Comment: Thank you,Axel. Would there be a workaround to achieve what I want to though?

Comment: looks like it does now, there are clearly many examples doing multiple statements in one migration file https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#sql-based-migrations#syntax